# Not able to download 6 to 7 million records with 80 columns in csv from SQL Server and C# application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, csv

I need to download an extract from my application created on asp.net C#. It reads from SQL Server 2008 and tries to write it into `.csv` file. There are 6 to 7 million rows with approx 80 columns. The application breaks and stops responding and I'm not able to download through web browser.

As an alternative I tried creating a windows service which runs on server to extract the data and create a csv file. But in case of multiple download request the server runs out of memory and the service breaks and stops working.

Total data in table is 700 MB and to read this the server memory reaches utilization of 5 GB out 8 GB for each request. In case if there are multiple async request the memory utilization goes to 100% and service stops and file is not generated.

Currently using data table and rows as follows, need a way to download the data using C# application on request or any other means which can generate the csv file from the data given from the stored procedure.

Thanks

```
// the method to extract data
public getdata( xyz ....)
{
    dbInstance = ConfigDBDAL.GetTransactionDBInstance(userDO);

    DbCommand dbCommand = dbInstance.GetStoredProcCommand(PR_GET_EXTRACTS);
    dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

    // a few parameter passing like this
    DbParameter paramStartDate = new SqlParameter("@StartDate", typeof(DateTime));
    paramStartDate.Value = startDate;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(paramStartDate);

    DbParameter paramStartDate = new SqlParameter("@EndDate", typeof(DateTime));
    paramStartDate.Value = startDate;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(paramStartDate);

    // Creating a data table for the required 80 columns 
    datatable = new DataTable();

    datatable.Columns.Add("COL1");
    datatable.Columns.Add("COL2");
    datatable.Columns.Add("COL3");
    .
    .
    .
    datatable.Columns.Add("COL80");

    using (IDataReader reader = dbInstance.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
    {
        DataRow newRow;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            row = datatable.NewRow();
            row["COL1"] = reader["COL1"];
            row["COL2"] = reader["COL2"];
            .
            .
            row["COL80"] = reader["COL80"];

            datatable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    return datatable;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `bcp` utility? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility

Comment: `The application breaks and stops responding and I'm not able to download through web browser.` Be more explicit about what this means. How does it work? What do you mean by not responding? Why are you not able to download (does it show an error? time out (and if so, after so long)? something else?)?

Comment: @RogerWolf : I need a real time file generation that takes place on placing a request from the application. No idea if I can handle it with bcp as the parameters passed to the SP can change as per user requirement

Comment: @mjwills : earlier I had a straight forward code that would fetch data from database as a data table and start writing to the .csv file which was working for small data size say 30 to 50 MB. Now as the data size and generated file grew to 350 - 400 mb, the application stops responding or say the request get killed in the middle. Even sometimes the Web Browser stops responding

Comment: @mjwills basically looks like their is a time out from application side while the data is still being fetched from the sql server. I tried making the time out in my DAL layer for the method to 0. still the same.

Comment: `say the request get killed in the middle` That was the exception / error shown? Can you copy and paste the `exact` message?

Comment: Please include the contents of your `PR_GET_EXTRACTS` stored proc in your post.

Comment: Does https://serverfault.com/questions/458505/iis7-how-to-configure-server-to-serve-large-gbs-files help?

Answer (score 2):

`DataTable` class produces some overhead. Try to build pure CSV string using `StringBuilder`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("sep=,");
sb.AppendLine("COL1,COL2,COL3,...,COL-N"); // columns

using (IDataReader reader = dbInstance.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
{
    DataRow newRow;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sb.Append((string)reader["COL1"] + ",");
        sb.Append((string)reader["COL2"] + ",");
        sb.Append((string)reader["COL3"] + ",");
        ...
        sb.Append((string)reader["COL-N"] + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

return sb.ToString(); // returns string representing CSV file content
```

Comment: It makes sense as it does not utilize my server memory and keeps on writing the the file directly. Although, feels a little slow when I've to download data that amounts to file size of 350 mb. Do we have any way to make work more fast.

Comment: @ParthKalra first, add a `StopWatch` and collect durations of query execution, reading all rows in DataReader (without building csv, just read and call ToString(), and finally measure full duration. Then you can find the slowest part of this procedure

Comment: @openwix: I tried adding the comments during the start and end of the execution of the SP that actually fetches the data. It takes almost 5 to 6 mins to get the data. As i'm over a tunnel network. It works like a charm in a min if I run it as a query mode on the server itself. But while running through application it takes  5-6 mins as it's over a vpn connection.

Comment: @openwix: I had tweaked your code a little, as i cannot keep on appending the data as the size of the data goes on increasing hence was creating a string builder in the while loop and writing it to the file so as to avoid memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this method.

```
public static void ExportPlantData(string channelId)
{
    string query = string.Empty;

    DataService dataService = new DataService();
    DbCommand dataCmd = null;
    DataTable contentToExport = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        query = "SELECT * from tablename";

        dataCmd = dataService.Database.GetSqlStringCommand(query);
        contentToExport = dataService.ExecuteDataTable(dataCmd);
        ExportToCSV(contentToExport);
    }    
}


public static void ExportToCSV(DataTable contentToexport)
{
    StringBuilder csvData = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder headers = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (DataRow row in contentToexport.Rows)
    {
        headers = string.Empty;
        foreach (DataColumn column in contentToexport.Columns)
        {
            csvData.Append(row[column].ToString() + ",");
            headers.Append(column.ColumnName + ",");
        }

       csvData.Append("\r\n");
       headers.Append("\r\n");
    }

    string contentToExport = headers.Append(csvData.ToString()).ToString();
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=export.csv";

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(contentToExport);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Comment: As per my code too I'm currently using Data Table to fetch data from the database. But as the size of data is huge the Server Memory get filled unless the data is written to the file from the Data Table. And in case of multiple request from to fetch data the server runs out of memory.